# Ace editor - insert text at position

Tags: ace-editor

I'm working on a real-time collaborative editor within Ace editor, and I couldn't find any docs on inserting text at a certain position within the editor (Aka, the position the other user types at.) Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use `editor.session.insert(position, text)` where position is an object of the form `{row:number, column:number}`
However this alone won't help to make collaborative editor. take a look at share.js which supports Ace.

Comment: Thanks! And I don't need help for the other part. I just wasn't sure how I could get the position/insert text. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 35):

To insert at current position you can use ( assuming that might be what you are looking for )

`editor.session.insert(editor.getCursorPosition(), text)`